# Using width specifier with printf with no variable

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I am working on a project for my C Programming Class.
I know that when specifying width in a printf statement **WITH** a variable, it would look like this:

```
printf("%03d\n", tvQuantity);
```

With 3 being the width and 0 stating we want the number preceded by 0's.

My question is, how would I define a width in a printf statement where I'm not calling a variable?
For example, to add a width of 6 to the following statement:

```
printf("Text here");
```

As there is no format specifier (such as %d), where would I place my width and other formatting arguments?

Comment: What would you expect a width of 6 to do there?

Comment: @Schwern I'm trying to output my data in a format similar to this https://imgur.com/a/Vb6PQCw

Comment: @RobertRDev So you do have variables?

Comment: Yes just not for the QTY, DESCRIPTION, UNIT PRICE, AND TOTAL PRICE column names

Comment: @RobertRDev Post  data here, not behind something  that may be [inaccessible](https://imgur.com/a/Vb6PQCw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("Text here");` needs no width. It'll just print `Text here`.

You could write it as `printf("%6s", "Text here")` but that will do nothing as the width is a minimum and the text is longer than 6 characters.

If you want to pad the text, say with a width of 20, you can write `printf("%20s\n", "Text here")`. This could be useful if the string was defined in a constant.

To format your text in columns, you'd use multiple `%s` formats in a single `printf`.

```
printf("%20s %20s %20s\n", "Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much!